# Qt application's live search not working on Huawei P8 Lite

Tags: android, qt, qml, huawei-mobile-services, livesearch

I'm making a mobile application on Qt Creator. The app includes live search which searches the Local Storage database.
I tried the app on Samsung devices and it works great, but the live search is not working on my Huawei 8 Lite.
Every time the qml TextField gains focus this error appears on the error log:

```
I HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
```

While I type on the TextField no search result appears.

**Edit:**

Here is a simplified version of the app:

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.LocalStorage 2.0

import "js/Data.js" as Data

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 360
    height: 480

    header: ToolBar {
        width: parent.width

        RowLayout {
            width: parent.width

            TextField {
                id: search
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                placeholderText: "Search..."

                onTextChanged: {
                    if (search.text.length > 0) {
                        Data.showSearch(search.text)
                    } else {
                        model.clear()
                    }
                }
            }

            ToolButton {
                icon.source: "icons/close.svg"
                onClicked: {
                    search.text = ""
                    search.focus = true
                }
            }
        }
    } // Header ends


    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent

        model: ListModel {
            id: model
        }

        delegate: Row {
            width: parent.width

            Text {
                text: number
            }

            Text {
                text: title
            }
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: Data.init()
}
```

js/Data.js

```
function showSearch(searchedText) {
    var db = LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("test_db", "", "", 1000000)
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        var results = tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM test')
        var i, haystack, needle = searchedText.toUpperCase()

        model.clear()

        for (i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
            haystack = results.rows.item(i).title.toUpperCase()
            if (haystack.indexOf(needle) > -1) {
                model.append({
                            number: results.rows.item(i).number,
                            title: results.rows.item(i).title,
                            star: results.rows.item(i).star
                        })
            }
        }
    })
}

function init() {
    var db = LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("test_db", "", "", 1000000)
    try {
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (number INTEGER, title TEXT, star INTEGER)');

            var r = tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM test');
            if (r.rows.length === 0) {
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO test VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [1, 'First', false]);
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO test VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [2, 'Second', false]);
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO test VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [3, 'Third', false]);
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO test VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [4, 'Fourth', false]);
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO test VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [5, 'Fifth', false]);
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO test VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [99, 'Ninety-ninth', false]);
            }

        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error creating table in database: " + err)
    };
}
```

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @folibis I added a simplified version of the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I changed the property change signal handler of the `TextField` from `onTextChanged` to `onDisplayTextChanged` and `text` property to `displayText`:

```
onDisplayTextChanged: {
    if (search.displayText.length > 0) {
        Data.showSearch(search.displayText)
    } else {
        model.clear()
    }
}
```

The live search is working on my Huawei device, although I'm still getting `I HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null` on `TextField` focus, but it seems that was not related to the search problem.